# Does light reflect only from the water surface, or deeper?

Tags: visible-light

[image: Photo of shadows cast by floating objects.]

The shadows in the picture are on the wall of the pool, above the waterline. If the sunlight coming from low at the right is reflected only from the surface, I would expect to see shadows of only the upper part of the floats. Since I see shadows even of the submerged part of the floats, I guess some of the reflection must be coming from within the water. Is that
correct?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you are right. For further queries you can watch this [QED videos by Richard Feynman](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eLQ2atfqk2c) You can observe the same phenomena when you look into a transparent glass, you can partially see your reflection and at the same time you can see what's  on the other side.